# Java Timer vs. Linux Cronjob

Tags: java, linux, timer, automation, cron

I'm doing automation on data fetching using Java , which approach is better for task automation? Linux cronjob or Java Timer?

for example the tasks to execute hourly, first day of week, first day of month, thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is unanswerable in it's current form. It depends on the task, environment, preference and a bunch of other parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the application to be always running for some other reason, and the data fetching happen frequently, you can consider using java task.

If you will write an application just for this purpose, or it is an  application you dont need to to be always open since its not perfoming other continuos action, i'd prefer a cronjob, so you can have the app out of the memory most time.

Also, notice cronjobs are very efficent, and fully trustable. So if the data frecuency is important and is not just related to some runtime features, i'd also prefer cronjob

This is just for mentioning a few high level scenarios, but as Keppil said, it could depend on many other aspects.

Comment: I got it now, thanks Carlos!

Comment: my pleasue! please mark the ansewr as valid if it was! :-)

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on what you want, but I will say that the times I have created automated tasks I have used cron jobs or Windows scheduled tasks.  As Carlos stated, the Java program would have to be running in order to even be able to perform the operations.  So if it is a production application and it dies, then the jobs can't be kicked off till it is brought back up again.  Also, setting up a cron job is typically easier than writing a program.

On the other had, if it is a system that you do not have admin rights to and are unable to create or edit cron jobs but are able to kick off a Java program, the Java program might be easier.

Overall, the cron job seems to be the industry "best practice" (sorry for the buzz word), but, again, it might depend on your specific situation.